# Indexing in Apache Solr

Tags: solr

I am very new to Apache Solr search engine . I have installed on my CENT OS VM and need to index the documents .Through the Apache Solr UI , I am able to put and index the document but Can I do the same through any JAVA API ? Kindly help me ... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SolrJ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ). For Solr, here are some links to get started.

1. [Apache Solr Reference Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Apache+Solr+Reference+Guide)
2. [Solr Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FrontPage)
3. [Yonik's Getting Started With Solr](http://yonik.com/getting-started-with-solr/)

Answer (score 0):

Use SolrJ

```
HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("<host>:<port>");
SolrQuery solrquery = new SolrQuery();
solrquery.setQuery("test");
solrquery.set("defType", "edismax");
solrquery.setHighlight(true);
QueryResponse queryResponse = solr.query(solrquery);
SolrDocumentList documentList = queryResponse.getResults();
```

Hope this helps :)